# Is "zu" necessary or change the meaning of the sentence if omitting it?

Tags: meaning, grammar-identification

Reading "Der Corona Schock" from *Hans-Werner Sinn*

What is the meaning of "zu" in this sentence on *page 81*? What is the grammar of "zu" use here? How does omitting "zu" change the meaning?

> Kurzum, genau dies ist das nur schwer zu lösende Problem des Euroraums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not that different from English, the problem is hard *to* solve. A complication, for which I could not give you a rule, is that *lösende* is actually an infinitive in disguise:

> Das Problem ist schwer zu lösen.
>
> Es ist ein schwer zu lösendes Problem.

Omitting the *zu* would, by accident, lead a grammatical sentence, but it would be non-sensical.

> Es ist ein schwer lösendes Problem.
>
> It is a hard solving problem.

So the problem would be solving something, hard. Here, *lösend* would be a present participle.